# Wrong use of fprintf? Getting exception First-chance exception

Tags: c++, exception, file-io, printf

I'm getting "First-chance exception at 0x708A6B2E (msvcr120.dll)" in the first line of print_bit_vector() in its second execution.
Can you tell why?

code:

```
void print_bit_vector(FILE* pFile, std::string title, std::vector<bool> bitVector) {
    fprintf(pFile, "%s:\r\n", title);
    int size = bitVector.size();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    //for (bool bit : bitVector)
        fprintf(pFile, "%d", bitVector.at(i));
    }
    fprintf(pFile, "\r\n");
}

void test() {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("C:\\...\\myfile.txt", "w");

    BC bc("C:\\...\\example_test.txt");
    std::vector<bool> key = std::vector<bool>(128, 0);
    std::vector<bool> input = std::vector<bool>(128, 1);

    print_bit_vector(pFile, "Key", key);
    print_bit_vector(pFile, "Input", input); //Exception inside this execution of print_bit_vector(...)

    bc.setInputsByParty(1, key);
    bc.setInputsByParty(2, input);

    std::vector<bool> outputs;
    bc.compute(outputs);   
    print_bit_vector(pFile, "Output", outputs);

    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because `%s` in printf actually wants a `char const *`, not a `std::string`.

You can use `title.c_str()` to get a `char const *` from a c++ string.

Comment: It actually wants a `char const*`.  But a `char*` is close enough.  (And `title.c_str()` will return a `char const*`, not a `char*`.)

Comment: Your solution worked but why is it failed only in the second execution?

Comment: @Bush _"but why is it failed only in the second execution? "_ That's the nature of undefined behavior, that we can't tell.

Comment: It failed on the second execution deterministicaly... isn't there a better cause than "undefined behaviour"?

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, you're right, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Bush Undefined behaviour does not means that your program will behave differently at each run. Chances are that your variable will be assigned to the same memory locations at each run, thus leading to the same issue.